# I want to create sub area within are in asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, directory-structure, asp.net-mvc-areas

```
Application
-> Area
    -> Customer
      -> New Customer
          1. NewCustomerListController.cs
          2. NewCustomerImportController.cs
      -> Old Customer
          1. OldCustomerUpdateController.cs
          2. NewCustomerExportController.cs


Can we create this type of structure in asp.net core 3.0
```

I want to create this type folders structure in asp.net core.

Comment: Areas provide a way to partition an ASP.NET Core Web app into smaller functional groups, each with its own set of Razor Pages, controllers, views, and models.  You can follow the structure in the dffical document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#area-folder-structure

Comment: yes it is possible with subarea attribute method.